# google cloud datastore making backups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I am new to Google Cloud and I am having a hard time figuring out whether it is making backups of the data or not? How can I check and if it is not making back-up, does anyone have any idea how I can look into making backups? Does it have anything to do with buckets? Also I am having a difficult time understanding what the link between buckets, Datastore and storage is. Also, in the Storage section there is a file that is created every day that ends in the extension "Activity.backup_info." How do you open this file ? I have tried to use notepad but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being a managed database, you are not responsible for high availability.  It handles sharding and replication for you.

However, if you wish to take backups of your data for logical recovery activities (eg restore your data to a previous point in time because you changed it inappropriately) you can use the built in export and import functions.  These are documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities).  At the highest level you have `gcloud` commands called:

- `gcloud datastore export`
- `gcloud datastore import`

That export / import your data to/from Google Cloud Storage (GCS).  These functions are also available through API meaning that you can automate these tasks (or schedule them based on time).

Comment: thank you for your reply.  I contacted google cloud and this is what they said: 
     "To reiterate, In order to have automatic backup in Cloud Datastore, you can do 
     so by having managed Export/Import for Datastore in Cloud Storage, here’s the 
     documentation[1]However if your request was regarding where you could verify 
     the backups are being done, you can do so by looking at the bucket you have 
    created for the Export/Import."
What do buckets have to do with this? How can i verify this, that backups are being made; that it is a managed database?

Comment: Google Cloud Storage (GCS) is a large scale managed storage product from Google.  https://cloud.google.com/storage/ ... it allows you to store data as blob objects.  Think of these as files.  It is the cheapest of the storage products and ideal for storing large amounts of data.  An object is named entity and is stored in a collection of such objects called a "bucket".  Putting it all together ... you would create a GCS bucket in your GCP project and then export your Datastore data to GCS objects in a GCS bucket.